# Is there any java equivalent Httpsessionlistener in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I wants to do some operations even after closing the session (manual or by instant). I can do whatever I want when the user clicking the link 'logout' but I don't see any option do the same when the user suddenly closing the browser.

Hence, I am looking for any listener kind of things similar in Java.

in Java:
http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionlistener-example-active-sessions-counter/

Answer (score 0):

Rails is stateless and doesn't support this type of behaviour directly. 
If your requirement can only be satisfied with this type of logic, then I can think of a number of ways you could work around this:

- Have the page continuously ping your server to let it know the
  connection is still alive. Run a cron job every reasonable interval
  to take whatever action you want on terminated sessions.

  - Or just say that any session not refreshed after 30 minutes or
    something is considered terminated.
- Create a javascript code run on page unload that notifies your app that
  the browser is closing. This is obviously not foolproof (connection
  drops, browser crashes, etc) and probably isn't viable.